# JBoss EAP6: 404 on my webapp

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jboss, http-status-code-404

I'm trying do deploy a simple Spring Boot webapp to JBoss EAP6 (default install, standalone mode, bind to 0.0.0.0, Debian 7.8 fresh install, iptable disabled, JDK8 as default jdk/jre).

I can show the default ROOT application (something like theRemoteIp:8080/).
I successfully deployed my webapp: JBoss indicates it is deployed, I also see my logs messages, it's ok.

#### Problem: I can't connect to my webapp, I always get a 404 error. No relevant error in my webapp or Jboss logs.

This application has a single page. This is a CRUD demo that connects to a MongoDB local database (webapp and MongoDB are correctly configured).

The webapp source code is hosted on github: https://github.com/jonathanlermitage/springboot-samples/tree/master/simple-nosql.
I also packaged and renamed the war file here: http://lermitage.biz/pub/files/foo.war.
It works fine on Tomcat 8.

Maybe I'm missing something?
I've tried to add a static resource but I also have a 404 error when querying it.

Thx for your support.

Comment: Okay, finally it was a problem with JBoss class loader. This %&@#§ server used its own version of some libs instead of webapp's libraries :p

Answer (score 0):

Your links don't seem to work making it harder to assist you.
When you deploy a war file to JBoss EAP6 it takes the name of the file without '.war' as context root. So when you deployed demo.war it will be accessible from /demo, unless you have added a jboss-web.xml to the WEB-INF folder.
In there you can specify the context root.

Grtz,
Marcel